# Is there a way to map over the cities on my cities array using the api and rendering the info from all cities on the array?

Tags: reactjs, api

Right now is only displaying the info for the first item. 
I stored the cities I want to get info from in the constant and now I 
I am trying to get the info from each to display. 
I am not sure how to go about it.

```
class HomePage extends Component {
  state = {
    weatherResults: []
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    const cities = ["Boston", "New York"];

    fetch(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?id=52490&units=imperial&appid=${API_KEY}&q=${cities}&cnt=60`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(results => {
        this.setState({
          weatherResults: results
        });
        console.log(results);
      })
      .catch(error => console.error(error));
  }

  render() {
    const { weatherResults } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.weatherResults.length !== 0 && (
          <div className="container" key={weatherResults.city.id}>
            <h2> {weatherResults.city.name} </h2>
            <p> {weatherResults.list[0].main.temp}</p>
            <p>{weatherResults.list[0].weather[0].description}</p>
            <p>
              Humidity:
              {weatherResults.list[0].main.humidity}
            </p>
            <p> Wind: {weatherResults.list[0].wind.speed} </p>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default HomePage;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a separate `fetch` request for each city and use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to put the result of both requests in the state when both requests have finished.

You can then use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) on the `weatherResults` array to display the information about both cities in the render method.

**Example**

```
class HomePage extends Component {
  state = {
    weatherResults: []
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    const cities = ["Boston", "New York"];

    const promises = cities.map(city => {
      return fetch(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?id=52490&units=imperial&appid=${API_KEY}&q=${city}&cnt=60`)
        .then(res => res.json());
    });

    Promise.all(promises)
      .then(weatherResults => {
        this.setState({ weatherResults });
      })
      .catch(error => console.error(error));
  }

  render() {
    const { weatherResults } = this.state;

    if (weatherResults.length === 0) {
      return null;
    }

    return (
      <div className="container">
        {weatherResults.map(weatherResult => (
          <div key={weatherResult.city.id}>
            <h2>{weatherResult.city.name}</h2>
            <p>{weatherResult.list[0].main.temp}</p>
            <p>{weatherResult.list[0].weather[0].description}</p>
            <p>Humidity: {weatherResult.list[0].main.humidity}</p>
            <p>Wind: {weatherResult.list[0].wind.speed}</p>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank again Tholle ! This is very helpful but I am trying to get the api to render this info for both the city of boston and new york. Do you know if this is possible?

Comment: @AngieSpears You're welcome! Ah, I think I misunderstood the question. I updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks Tholle! I am new at this so I probably didn't ask correctly! This makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this.

```
render() {
  const { weatherResults } = this.state;
     return (
         <div>
             { this.state.weatherResults.length &&
             <div className = "container">
               <h2> { weatherResults.city.name}  </h2>
             </div>
             }
         { 
          this.state.weatherResults.list.map((ele, idx) => (
              <div>
               <p> {ele.main.temp}</p>
               <p> 
                 {ele.weather[0].description} 
              </p>
              <p> Humidity: 
                 {ele.main.humidity} </p>
             <p> Wind: {ele.wind.speed} </p>
         </div>
          ))
        }
      </div>
     );
   }
  }
```

Essentially what I'm doing above is creating an array of react components and displaying them based on content in your list. Now I'm not 100% sure what your JSON structure looks like so i just made assumptions based on the code you posted above.

If possible id move all the content related to the JSON into the map function.

This portion:

```
{ this.state.weatherResults.length &&
         <div className = "container">
           <h2> { weatherResults.city.name}  </h2>
         </div>
         }
```

Also it is recommended that each element in the array/map call have its own unique key that is not the index. so if the JSON contains some unique identifier like a primary key from a data base use it.

Comment: Hi Joshua, Thank you for your help! So do I need to undated the cities array in order to make this work?

Comment: not sure what you mean by "undated the cities array"

Comment: I am essentially trying to pull information from a couple of cities using the weather api. So, I created a const called cities with an array of the cities I want to obtain info from.  I apologize if I still don't make sense, I am new at this... Thanks for your help again!

Comment: no problem at all ill do my best to help. since I'm not familiar with the api you are using, i have a few questions about it after querying for the two cities in the JSON do you see anything that differentiates Boston  from New York?

Answer (score 0):

To render items from Array in React you should use [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

For example:

```
  render() {
    const { weatherResults } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {
          weatherResults.list.length > 0 && 
          weatherResults.list.map(item => (
            <div className="container" key={weatherResults.city.id}>
              <h2> {item.city.name} </h2>
              <p> {item.main.temp}</p>
              <p>{item.weather[0].description}</p>
              <p>Humidity: {item.main.humidity}</p>
              <p> Wind: {item.wind.speed} </p>
            </div>
         ));
       }
      </div>
    );
  }
```